# How to get workflow moderator comments in AEM custom workflow process?

Tags: workflow, aem

I am developing a custom approval/rejection workflow process, where I want to send moderator/approver comments to workflow initiator through email. How can I achieve this?

Is there any api present.

Answer (score 0):

Custom workflow email notification configurations

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/notification.html
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-custom-aem-workflow-steps.html
http://scottsdigitalcommunity.blogspot.com/2013/10/creating-custom-aem-workflow-steps-that.html

Comment: pls provide some context in the answer in case these links go offline. Refer [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)